# Calling a child method from a button on a parent vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, parent-child

I want to call the toggleDetails method of postDetails from the parent component's img tag and I don't seem to understand how to make it work.

Parent:

```
<div v-for="post in loggedInUser.posts" :key="post._id">

        <postDetails :post="post"></postDetails>

      <img @click.prevent="toggleDetails" class="grid-item" :src="post.imgUrl" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <section v-if="this.isDetailsOpen"> 
{{this.post.desc}}
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 props: {
    post: Object,
  },
 data() {
    return {
    isDetailsOpen: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDetails() {

      this.isDetailsOpen = !this.isDetailsOpen;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to emit an event from parent to child, you can do something like this:

### Parent component:

```html
<postDetails
  ref="post"
  :post="post"
></postDetails>

<img 
  @click.prevent="toggleDetails()" 
  class="grid-item" 
  :src="post.imgUrl" 
/>
```

```js
methods: {
  toggleDetails () {
    this.$refs.post.toggleDetails()
  }
}
```

### Child component:

```js
methods: {
  toggleDetails () {
    this.isDetailsOpen = !this.isDetailsOpen
  }
}
```

But to be able to send events between any components you would have to create an eventBus (eventHub).